# Has anyone set up auto-scaling mysql or maridb cluster with Jelastic v4.9+

Tags: mysql, mariadb, jelastic

I'm interested about creating auto-scaling database cluster (mysql or mariadb) with Jelastic.

The latest version of Jelastic supports auto-scaling features for all certified paas and docker containers and I wonder how use this feature with database instances.

Has anyone already sorted this out? please how?

Comment: dba.SE is a better place for questions about database design.

Comment: The autoscaling for databases is a quite difficult question, so could you please kindly provide us with your use case for this feature and mark the main points according to your needs. Maybe you have some examples of such implementation?

Comment: A main point about DB horizontal scaling is to explain what you want / expect to get from that. DB servers do not usually scale well horizontally - i.e. you do not usually get significantly more performance / capacity from doing that because there are certain technical bottlenecks about keeping the DB state synchronised for writes (read-only scaling is quite possible and relatively trivial to implement however).

Comment: Yes, you're true, in most cases it's enough to read-only scale and provide more resources for browsing user's of web application. Anyway I'm curious about how to config db scaling. For example how to direct read-operations to read-only nodes when scaling up and what to do when scaling down.

Comment: HAproxy is the easiest way to direct requests to multiple read only slaves. Jelastic can be instructed to update HAproxy conf on scale in/out

Comment: Thx Damien, you're the greatest! I'll check this later.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to scale DB containers with Jelastic since v.4.9.1. This feature works with help of tunable triggers and when they are executed - Jelastic will create a new clean DB-node/s of the same type in this environment. This case is pretty custom, so the user has to set up a proper configuration for replication and all behavior after scaling with help of cloud scripting.